# add a class (on hover) to a pool of targets, but not to the hovered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, addclass

I have a number of elements across the site and would like to blur them when hovering over them - only leaving the hovered element in focus.

What is the shorter way to achieve this? I came up with this dumb code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#a').hover(function() {
    $('#b, #c, #d, #e').addClass("blur");
  }, function() {
    $('#b, #c, #d, #e').removeClass("blur");
  }),

  $('#b').hover(function() {
    $('#a, #c, #d, #e').addClass("blur");
  }, function() {
    $('#a, #c, #d, #e').removeClass("blur");
  }),

  $('#c').hover(function() {
    $('#a, #b, #d, #e').addClass("blur");
  }, function() {
    $('#a, #b, #d, #e').removeClass("blur");
  }),

  $('#d').hover(function() {
    $('#a, #b, #c, #e').addClass("blur");
  }, function() {
    $('#a, #b, #c, #e').removeClass("blur");
  }),

  $('#e').hover(function() {
    $('#a, #b, #c, #d').addClass("blur");
  }, function() {
    $('#a, #b, #c, #d').removeClass("blur");
  });
});
```

Thanks:>!

Comment: You're right... that is awful. :-) Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.my-class').hover(function() {
    $('.my-class').not(this).addClass('blur');
}, function() {
    $('.my-class').removeClass('blur');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7VzBf/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with CSS by using the `:not`-selector and `CSS Filters`.

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div:not(:hover) { 
    blur(1px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -ms-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zHxGn

This will select every element that does not get hovered and blur it using CSS Filters.
The problem with that solution is that the browser-support is fairly limited at the moment:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

For a broader support you would need something like Foggy.
http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/

You could use it like that:

```
// Set up blur on each element
$('div').foggy({blurRadius: 2, opacity: 1});

$('div').hover(function() {
  // Delete blur on mouseenter
  $(this).foggy(false);
}, function() {
  // Blur again on mouseout
  $(this).foggy({blurRadius: 2, opacity: 1})
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yIotA

---

Edit:

If you want your elements unblurred until you hover over one of them, you can do it like that:

```
$('div').hover(function() {
  // Blur every other element on mouse enter
 $('div:not(:hover)').foggy({blurRadius: 2, opacity: 1});
}, function() {
  // Delete Blur on mouse out
  $('div').foggy(false);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DJCBI

Comment: thanks! I've tried the css with selectors way myself, but need the elements to be unblured when not hovered.

Comment: @Loutseau that would be the part I had edited in. ;)

Comment: i see, thank you :) i hope i wont have to rely on foggy to handle blur, but if i do, i'll make sure I give you the right answer :D